# The no-startup-window option does not working on Windows

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Hi !

I am currently using Chrome with Selenium on Windows 7 OS, and I tried to use the  `--no-startup-window`with. However this option crashed the Selenium with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program_test.py", line 234, in <module>
    main()
  File "program_test.py", line 36, in main
    initChromeWebDriver()
  File "c:\opt\project\auto\common\driver.py", line 27, in initChromeWebDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "c:\opt\project\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.p
y", line 67, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "c:\opt\project\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.p
y", line 91, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "c:\opt\project\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.p
y", line 173, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "c:\opt\project\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.p
y", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "c:\opt\project\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandle
r.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to st
art: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platfo
rm=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

There is my piece of code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-startup-window")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Without this option, Chrome is able to launch if I comment the line.

Any idea about this issue ?

Comment: hi, were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @pratibha: Unfortunately not, I gave up. I think you will maybe need to open a ticket to Chrome for their Web Driver... If you find a solution after your research, Please post an answer, I will be very interested :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome 59 comes with "--headless" option. I use it with Python 2.7 and Selenium 3. Worked like a charm. Just try "--headless" in place of "--no-startup-window"

Comment: Ok, I will try soon as the Chrome 59 raised :)

Comment: confirmed it still works on chrome v80. "--no-startup-window" is deprecated, as well as "chrome_options" parameter in webdriver.Chrome, use only "options" instead.